# form_with not submitting as AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a form in my app that I'm declaring in the following way:

```
= form_with model: project, remote: true, method: :put do |f|
  = f.select :selected_draw, options_for_select(project.draws.pluck(:number, :id), draw.id), {}, class: 'form-control', onchange: "this.form.submit()"
```

And I can't seem to be able to make it submit as a remote form, even though in other parts of my app I do use remote forms and on this form it does set the `data-remote` attribute on the form. Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you forgot format.js in controller?

Comment: `form_with` uses ajax submit by default unless it's overwritten somewhere. Have you tried replacing `remote: true` with `local: true`? `remote` is not an option with `form_with` I don't think https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

Comment: @Catmal it is there, the request is just reaching the controller as a normal form submit

Comment: @kasperite it does take it, if you look at the docs, it's just not working for some reason.

Comment: Do you have `//= require jquery_ujs` or `//= require rails-ujs` in `application.js`?

Comment: @HDox yes, I have` jquery_ujs` in there

Comment: Just tried using rails-ujs instead of jquery_ujs and it doesn't work. The weird thing I have other forms using remote: true and they work.

Comment: Are you uploading any files via that form? Because file upload can not work with remote form.

Comment: @HDox no file upload, it's just a string. The entirety of the form is what I posted in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `this.form.submit()` does not trigger the 'submit' event so the Rails callbacks to process it as a remote form are not called.

Use `onchange="Rails.fire(this.form, 'submit')"` instead. That way you tell Rails javascript objects to fire the event.

EDIT: that's using rails-ujs, I'm not sure if it's the same with jquery-ujs though

Comment: I got Uncaught ReferenceError: Rails is not defined

Comment: Do you have rails-ujs on your application.js?